# The videos downloaded from my phone onto my laptop do not work smoothly

Tags: windows-8, laptop, video, android, windows-10-upgrade

I recently upgraded my laptop to Windows 10 and I think that after the update, any videos I try to play on my laptop do turn on, but the voice is fidgety and robotic. I can't hear anything on the videos. And the videos themselves do not play correctly, either. I see the picture, but it keeps jerking and it is very pixelated. They used to work fine with Windows 8, but not anymore.

Is there any way I can fix this?

I will be changing my phone soon (Samsung Galaxy S4 Android) and I want to save all the videos to my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time windows or other operating systems try to install generic drivers when they didn't get exact driver matching to respected host machine. Generic drivers are just letting the features work but not in efficient manner because they perform proxy task.

You need to confirm either windows 10 does support vga, sound drivers related to your machine or download and install latest drivers which support windows 10 + your machine.